# Como remover o ícone do onesignal?

Tags: java, android

Galera tem um aplicativo no Android Studio e ele tem notificações da One Signal, está funcionando normal, consegui mudar o ícone padrão para um de minha escolha, porém fica o meu ícone e outro ícone pequeno ao lado, gostaria de deixar somente o icone grande e tirar esse icone pequeno, alguém sabe remover ?

Comment: Descreva melhor o seu cenário e apresente o material pertinente para verificação.

Comment: Na notificação do onesignal tem 2 icones 1 grande e 1 pequeno, eu gostaria de remover o pequeno

Comment: Olha http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/29299a77-b417-4000-8467-bc8a70660dac-jpg

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o ícone pequeno é o ícone do aplicativo, e o grande é para a notificação em si, e nenhum dos dois pode ser removido.